# To return to 2 values using angularjs custom filter and show them differently on UI

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have an array which has time stored in minutes format, I am trying to change it into hr mm format. e.g: if its 0150, it should convert into 2hr 30min using this custom filter.
 Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>



<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{x | myFormat:hr}} hours {{x | myFormat:min}} mins
</li>
</ul>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x,hr,min) {

        var i, c, txt = "",hr,min;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            c = x[i];

            txt = txt+ c;
        }
           hr=txt/60;  //hr
           min=txt%60; //mins 

           if(hr>12)
          {
            hr=hr-12;
          }

         return min,hr;
    };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        '1350',
        '1200',
        '0060',
        '360',
        '0720',
        '1140',
        '960',
        '870',
        '330'

        ];
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

How am I suppose to return 2 values and then use valid syntax for custom filter to show it properly. 
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: How [c] is related here?

Comment: Try `return ({min: min, max: hr})`.... one object with two properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x,type) {

        var i, c, txt = "",hr,min;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            c = x[i];

            txt = txt+ c;
        }
           hr=txt/60;  //hr
           min=txt%60; //mins 

           if(hr>12)
          {
            hr=hr-12;
          }
      if(type=='min'){
        return min;
      } else{
        return Math.floor(hr);
      }

         return min,hr;
    };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        '1350',
        '1200',
        '0060',
        '360',
        '0720',
        '1140',
        '960',
        '870',
        '330'

        ];
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{x | myFormat:'hr'}} hours {{x | myFormat:'min'}} mins
</li>
</ul>
```

All functions in JS only return one thing (it can be a complex object or an array though).  In the case of angular filters it's expected that they return a string.  Simply concatenate the two values in the way you want it to be displayed `return min+":"+hr`

Just read through your code again and see you really want to just pass an argument to the filter and have it conditionally return one of the two values.  So do that.  make sure in the filter usage you put quotes around the 'min' or 'hr' so they don't get parsed as expressions and evaluated against the scope.  In your filter function it will get an input and then the arguments.  Before you return you can check if the arg is 'min' or 'hr' and return the appropriate part.

Comment: btw what does math.floor do?

Comment: @SanketDhoble np accept the answer if it helps so others can see this works.  Math.floor just gets rid of any fractional part, after I ran your code I saw it was showing 10.5 and the like for the hours, figured that .5 should be clipped off so floor will just round down to nearest integer.

Comment: Ah the mystery downvotes bringing me back to the good ol' days :)